# Obtain Facebook Page Access-Token

Tags: facebook, access-token

I am using the following code to publish a post to Facebook using PHP. I only have one problem left... I want to know how can I obtain an access-token for my page before publishing the post as access-tokens are not permanent.

> 

```
function status_update($status_text)
{
    require_once("facebook/facebook.php");

    $config = array();
    $config['pageId'] = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    $config['appId'] = 'yyyyyyyyyy';
    $config['secret'] = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzz';
    $config['fileUpload'] = false;

    $fb = new Facebook($config);

    $params = array(
      "access_token" => $config['appId'] . "|" . $config['secret'],
      "message" => $status_text,
      "link" => "http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php",
      "picture" => "http://i.imgur.com/lHkOsiH.png",
      "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
      "caption" => "www.pontikis.net",
      "description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation."
    );

    try
    {
      $ret = $fb->api('/xxxxxxxxxx/feed', 'POST', $params);
      echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
    } 
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

}
?>

Comment: RTFDocs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 1):

I have built a facebook app about **four month ago**, therefore I am not aware if any changes occurred. But I'll try help.

When you get an access to a page that you manage, you get a non-expiring access token, not 60 days, not several hours, but permanent one.

So, say you have a normal access token for an app and you want to gain privileges to, say post to you page. You want to check if you have a permission and if not:

```
// PHP condition here to show this piece of JS only if user has no permission 'manage_pages'
// see *1
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me/permissions?access_token={CURRENT_TOKEN}', function (response) {
            // Do whatever you want here, you have a response
            // For example:
            if (response['data'][0]['manage_pages'] === undefined) {
                // Will refresh if you deny when Facebook modal window appears
                top.location.href = '{SELF_URL}';
            }
        });
    } else {
      // ...
    }
}, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
```

***1** - You can retrieve your permissions by calling `->api('/me/permissions?access_token={YOUR_TOKEN}');` to use for checking for above snippet server side

***2** - You should also have initial rights as `publish_actions` `publish_stream` requested perhaps upon authorizing an application to have your rights to

Comment: I can help more if this answer does not cover your needs

Answer (score 0):

Just do it as it's descibed in the FB docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens

You can do this in the Graph Explorer:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer